# Java Dictionary like from Python

Tags: java, python, dictionary, arraylist

So I have been searching and searching all day, but I cannot seem to find how to create my dictionary I created in Python and create something similar in Java. I have tried looking at ArrayList and List etc. But to no avail.

```
PIECESDICT = {1: [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,1]], 2: [[0,0], [1,0], [0,1]], 3: [[0,0], [0,1], [1,1]], 4: [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]], 5: [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]]}
```

So here is my Dictionary, and essentially what it does is just says from coords (0,0) being the top left point of each piece. It is a piece in and of itself.

For example Piece 1 would look like:

```
0
00
0
```

Similarly Piece 2 would look like:

```
00
0
```

Comment: You could try a HashMap.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to use that similar to a dictionary?

Comment: If you've been searching all day, you should work on your search terms. The first google hit for `Java dictionary` is the (admittedly obsolete) [Dictionary class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html), and reading the class description would have pointed you towards `Map`. Searching `Java map` yields [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) as the second hit, which is an extensive introduction to the topic. But actually, if all your keys are numbers from 1 upwards like in your example, you could just use a list...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

The way you could use it:

```
Map<Integer, Integer[][]> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer[][]>();
Integer[][] v1 = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 }, { 1, 1 } };
map.put(1, v1);
```

Comment: Or just `Map<Integer, int[][]>`...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want... a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) of [`ArrayList`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of some kind of pair or coordinate object.

If you have a `Pair` class that accepts the coordinates as arguments (e.g. `new Pair(0, 0)`), then you can just do something like the following:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair>>();

ArrayList<Pair> first = new ArrayList<Pair>();
first.add(new Pair(1, 2));
first.add(new Pair(3, 4));

map.put(1, first);

// map == {1: [[1,2], [3,4]]}
```

`HashMap` can also accept a `String` (instead of `Integer`) as a key for the lists within.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense! I don't know why I didn't look into something like that earlier. I was originally looking more so into an ArrayList of an ArrayList of an ArrayList, so thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 2):

what about HashMap?
for example:
map.put("name", "value");

Comment: Yes a Hashmap will work, I do like the idea, but then how do I include the `[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1]]`

Comment: You can choose what the Object in the value will be.. you can decide that it will array of Point (which you should define)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move data from Python to Java, check out JSON.

In Python, you could use http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

And for Java: http://json.org/java/

Comment: How does JSON help here? The OP wanted to implement a data structure in Java and gave a Python structure as an example of what was needed. Where does it talk about moving data?